# How to execute an SQL statement stored in a shell script variable using isql

Tags: shell, isql, isqlquery

So, I am trying to execute an SQL statement stored in a shell script variable using isql

Generic code attached.

```
SQL="select * from Student"

EMPLOYEES=`isql -U $USERNAME -P $PASSWORD -D $DATABASE -S $SERVER<<EOF
$SQL
go
```

However on executing this, I get an error such as: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Select' and Incorrect suntax near '='

Anyone knows how to execute the SQL query directly stored in a variable from isql?

Comment: Your "here document" is not closed (no single line with "EOF") and also your backticks are not closed. Is this a copy/paste error on your part?

Comment: Seems like I had forgotten to paste the EOF.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try in this way:

```
EMPLOYEES=`echo "$SQL" | isql -U $USERNAME -P $PASSWORD -D $DATABASE -S $SERVER`
```

Comment: Thanks, turns out I was using in double quotes from the file where these SQL statements were being picked up. Taking them off and adding the EOF worked.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this page](http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-as/asg1250e/util/@Generic__BookTextView/1092), the following should work:

```
   SQL="select * from Student"

   EMPLOYEES=`isql -U $USERNAME -P $PASSWORD -D $DATABASE -S $SERVER<<EOF
   $SQL
   go
   EOF
   `
```

Also see my comment to your question, because in the code you posted you were lacking the closing "EOF" and backtick (each on a separate line).

You could also try to do it as @user1254184 has suggested in his answer:

```
   EMPLOYEES=`echo "$SQL" | isql -U $USERNAME -P $PASSWORD -D $DATABASE -S $SERVER`
```

Finally, to work around potential issues with quotes, etc. you could use a temporary file:

```
   echo "$SQL" > $TMP/sql.$$
   EMPLOYEES=`isql -U $USERNAME -P $PASSWORD -D $DATABASE -S $SERVER -i $TMP/sql.$$`
   rm $TMP/sql.$$
```

You may want to choose a better name for the temporary file.

Comment: Neat, this is an interesting solution